# QT5 using multipule .UI files

Tags: qt5

I have 3 .UI files that i'm trying to link together.  The first is a main menu that only has 2 buttons on it.  Each button should 1.) close the MainMenu.UI window and 2.)display the .UI file associated with that button.

My problem is I cant find any functions that either hide or display the currently used .UI file.  I also can't find a way to reference the other .UI files from the button1_onClick() function in the MainMenu.UI file.

hope I didn't make this more confusing than it needed to be, just trying to link together .UI files with buttons

EDIT:
I have been to the [QWindow Class docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qwindow.html#setWindowState) to try and find a function that does what I'm looking for but I can't seem find anything useful.

I finally figured out how access the show() and hide() methods so all i need now is to figure out how to reference other .UI files so I can show() or hide() those also.  I tried using the SetWindowFilePath() function passing it the file path of another .ui file but this didn't work either

```
this->hide();
this->setWindowFilePath("C:/Users/Scott/Desktop/...blah blah... /mainui.ui");
this->show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't hide or show .ui files, the C++ code generated from those files are wrapped into C++ classes which are derived directly or indirectly from QWidget and the instances of those classes can use *show()* or *hide()*

To use two Qt "forms" read this [faq](http://www.qtcentre.org/faq.php?faq=qt_general_category#faq_qt_designer_2forms) and ask specific questions (and maybe show some code) if you still can't get it to work.